# How should I communicate between private and non-private windows in a Chrome extension (manifest V3)?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The extension I'm making should open a link to a login screen in a private window, then fill out the login with info on the same non-private tab the link is on.

I'm using a service worker to receive messages from the non-private tab successfully. But I'm having issues sending a message from the service worker to the private window. Is this how I should be doing the communication? Are there different instances of the service worker for each Chrome window?

I'm fairly new to chrome extension development, so the problem may not be related to the window being private. I just want to know if I'm approaching it completely wrong before troubleshooting more.

(I didn't include code, since I wanted this to get a more generic answer that would be useful for other people to see. But I can include code if necessary.)

Comment: Use chrome.runtime messaging same as in MV2. If it doesn't work for you, add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question that shows how and when you create those windows and the communication code.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem!
I was trying to address the active tab, which did not switch to the new private tab I opened. I replaced it with the new tab sending a message to the service worker requesting info and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, so I'm just answering in case anyone else comes across it.
The Service Worker is the same for private and non-private windows and both types of windows behave the same in regards to chrome.runtime messages.